# Count B:H value based on column A value

Tags: excel

I want to count occurrences of a value X within a range (B1:H38) only if the column A value in that row is value Y.

I got close with the following, but it gives a #VALUE! Error and I don’t think it’s the right fit for what I need:

=COUNTIFS(A1:A38,“Y”,B1:H38,”X”)

What is the correct way to do this?

Edit 1:
Column A is either blank, or one of 5 words.
Columns B through H are either blank, words, or numbers.
In my mind, the logic is: find items in A that match “Y”, then check the rest of the row from B to H for “X”.
There may be 0, 1, or up to 7 matches in a given row.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data (eg does it contain blanks or errors).

Comment: Yes, there are blanks but no errors. I’m not sure how to paste the data, but column A are sort of categories that can be “Call”, “Backup” or a few other options, or blank. The B:H range can be any number of random text or numbers or blank, but I’m looking for specific names (will be matched based on another list, but I can make that part work if I can test by matching something discrete like “X”)

Comment: Does your version of Excel have the FILTER() function available?

Comment: Doesn’t look like it. Just FILTERXML. It’s 2016

Comment: OK, there may be ways, but I'm not best placed as my Excel version is different from yours, so I cant test (and array functions have changed). Easiest way is to create a new column with the formula `=IF(A1="Y",COUNTIF(B1:H1,"X"),0)`, fill this down and then SUM it.

Comment: I can’t seem to get that to work, since it only looks at one row in A at a time. In order to make that work, I’d have to create a new column for every value X that I’m checking, which would get pretty messy. It seems like I need Filter, which doesn’t exist. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

u already done it right.. it just that you formula is for 1 (one) time count.. not repeated @ every row .

```
=COUNTIFS(A1,“Y”,B1:H1,”X”)
```

put that in C1, then draq downwards. That should do.

Please share if it works/not/understandable. ( :